# Auto creado por y modificado por en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy usando `Python3` y `Django2` para un proyecto, ahora estoy creando una clase abstracta que sera heredada por todas las clases de mi proyecto, esto para determinar quien creo un registro y quien fue el ultimo que lo modifico. Para esto estoy usando un `Middleware` basándome en este ejemplo que encontré en la siguiente web [clic aquí](https://gist.github.com/jsanchezpando/4344176).

A continuación dejare el código como lo estoy usando:

Archivo `utils.py`:

```
import threading


_thread_locals = threading.local()


def set_current_user(user):
    _thread_locals.user = user


def get_current_user():
    return getattr(_thread_locals, 'user', None)


def remove_current_user():
    _thread_locals.user = None
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class ControlUsuarios(models.Model):
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('fecha de creación'))
    fecha_modificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True,
                                              verbose_name=_('fecha de modificación'))
    creador_por = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, editable=False, related_name='%(class)s_creador_por',
                                    on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    modificado_por = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, editable=False, related_name='%(class)s_modificado_por',
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ip_creacion = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('ip de creación'))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.fecha_creacion = datetime.today()
        else:
            self.fecha_modificacion = datetime.today()

        user = get_current_user()
        if user and user.is_authenticated():
            self.modificado_por = user
            if self._state.adding:
                self.creador_por = user
        super(ControlUsuarios, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Archivo `middleware.py`:

```
from aplicaciones.parametros.utils import set_current_user, remove_current_user

# Seccion inicial del sitio web
class CurrentUserMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        set_current_user(getattr(request, 'user', None))

# Consejos adicionales del sitio web
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        set_current_user(getattr(request, 'user', None))

        response = self.get_response(request)

        remove_current_user()
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

Archivo `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE  = [
    # ...
    ' aplicaciones.parametros.middleware.CurrentUserMiddleware ' ,
]
```

Con el `Middleware` ocurren 2 cosas.

1. Si lo uso como se ve en la primer sección de la web me sale el siguiente error antes de poder correr el servidor:

   ```
   TypeError: CurrentUserMiddleware() takes no arguments
   ```
2. Adiciono los consejos que se dan mas abajo con los métodos `__init__` y `__call__` aplicado esto me permite correr el servidor, pero me genera el siguiente error al intentar guardar un registro:

   ```
   TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
   ```

Y me indica que el problema ocurre en la clase `save` del modelo `Usuario` cerca de la linea condicional `if user and user.is_authenticated():`

Por ultimo, quiero agregar automáticamente la `ip` desde donde se crea el registro, como puedo implementar `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` en el `middleware`

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar con este tema.

---

**Solución al error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`**

El error `'bool' object is not callable` era debido a  que `user.is_authenticated` se debe usar como una propiedad y no como una función en el condicional. También ajuste el código para que el actualizado por solo se ejecute cuando ya exista el creado por:

```
user = get_current_user()
        if user and user.is_authenticated:
            if self._state.adding:
                self.creador_por = user
            else:
                self.modificado_por = user
        super(ControlUsuarios, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

**Pendiente:**

Sigo teniendo la duda de como implementar `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` en el `Middleware` cualquier ayuda o guía que me puedan dar les agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion la obtuve instalando la libreria `django-crum` que me permite acceder al request desde el modelo.

se instala el middleware

```
    MIDDLEWARE = (
        ...
        # Captura el request actual y el usuario en el almacenamiento local de subprocesos.
        'crum.CurrentRequestUserMiddleware',
)
```

Y mi Modelo quedo de la siguiente forma

```
class ControlUsuarios(models.Model):
    # Auditoria de creación
    creado_por = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_creado_por',
                                    verbose_name='creado por', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('fecha de creación'))
    ip_creacion = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('ip de creación'))
    # Auditoria de modificación
    modificado_por = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_modificado_por',
                                       verbose_name='modificado por', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_modificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('fecha de modificación'))
    ip_modificacion = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('ip de modificación'))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            self.creado_por = get_current_user()
            self.ip_creacion = get_current_request().META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        else:
            self.modificado_por = get_current_user()
            self.ip_modificacion = get_current_request().META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        super(ControlUsuarios, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```